# Jboss Patch Updates from 6.4.0 to 6.4.19

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x

I have installed Jboss EAP 6.4.0 and I am trying to upgrade it to the patch 6.4.19 but facing the following exception whenever I try this using jboss-cli tool:

> [standalone@localhost:9999 /] patch apply ../../jboss-eap-6.4.19-patch.zip
>   **JBAS016840: Patch does not apply - expected (6.4.9.GA), but was (6.4.0.GA)**

Note: jboss-eap-6.4.19-patch.zip contains 10 folders "jboss-eap-6.4.10.CP.zip" till "jboss-eap-6.4.19.CP.zip"

Answer (score 0):

We will have to install all the JBoss patch updates from 6.4.1 till 6.4.9 to start update patch for further 6.4.10 till 6.4.19

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the patch "jboss-eap-6.4.9-patch.zip" first before applying "jboss-eap-6.4.19-patch.zip"